# Why can't I found the page of the post ine a blog?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a problem with my code. I'am trying to realize a simple blog. Displaying the list of all the posts works. But when I click on a specific post the page of this post doesn't work.

This is the structure of my folder

[image: This is the structure of my folder]

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
require_once('controleurs/Controleur.php');
require_once('modeles/Modele.php');
require_once('modeles/Photo.php');
require_once('modeles/Photos.php');
$controleur = new Controleur();
if (isset($_GET['page']) && 'photo' === $_GET['page']) {
    $controleur->afficherPhoto();
} else {
    $controleur->listerPhotos();
}
```

Here is my Controleur.php :

```
class Controleur
{
    public function listerPhotos()
    {
        $photos = new Photos();
        $photos = $photos->listerPhotos();
        require_once('vues/liste-photos.php');
    }

    public function afficherPhoto()
    {
        $photo = new Photo();
        if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
            $photo = $photo->afficherPhoto($_GET['id']);
        }
        require_once('vues/affiche-photo.php');
    }
}
```

Here is class Photo.php

```
class Photo
{
    use Modele;

    private $id;

    private $fichier;

    private $titre;

    public function afficherPhoto($id)
    {
        if (!is_null($this->pdo)) {
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM photo WHERE id = ?');
        }
        $photo = null;
        if ($stmt->execute([$id])) {
            $photo = $stmt->fetchObject('Photo');
            if(!is_object($photo)) {
                $photo = null;
            }
        }

        return $photo;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFichier()
    {
        return $this->fichier;
    }

    public function getTitre()
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }
}
```

Here is my liste-photos.php (it works!)

```
<?php
$titre = 'Mon book';
ob_start();
?>
  <article>
    <?php foreach ($photos as $photo): ?>
      <a href="photo.php?id=<?= $photo->getId() ?>">
      <img src="photos/<?= $photo->getFichier() ?>" width="250"/>
      </a>
      <h2><?= $photo->getTitre() ?></h2>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </article>
  <?php
$contenu = ob_get_clean();
require_once('layout.php');
```

Here is my affiche-photo.php (it doesn't works!) :

```
$titre = 'Une photo de mon book';
if (is_null($photo)):
    $contenu = "Cette photo n'existe pas.";
else:
    ob_start();
?>
        <article>
            <img src="photos/<?php $photo->getFichier(); ?>" width="500" />
            <h2><?php $photo->getTitre(); ?></h2>
        </article>
<?php
    $contenu = ob_get_clean();
endif;
require_once('layout.php');
```

Thank you if you can help!!!

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I have my index.php with the list of all the posts. When I click on one of them I want to see the page of the post (using the id in the url). But I have an error Not Found with the url BookPhoto/photo.php?id=1

Comment: You're getting 500 errorcode on the photo's page or 200? Do you see any info there? What info doesn't exist there?

Comment: It tells me:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/8.0.1 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Ì think my code doesn't write the good url but I don't understand why

Comment: _Side note:_ When you add links to your question, you don't need to write "Click!". You can probably assume everyone here knows how links work :-)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why you didn't see the result is because you didn't print the values. You've used `<?php $value ?>` instead of `<?php echo $value; ?>`.
Also, according to the official documentation within [fetchObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php)

```
class Photo
{
    use Modele;

    private $id, $fichier, $titre; 
  
    private function __construct () {}

    public function afficherPhoto($id)
    {
        if (!is_null($this->pdo)) {

            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM photo WHERE id = ?');

            if ($stmt->execute([$id])) {
                return $stmt->fetchObject(__CLASS__);
            }
        }

        return null;
    } 
}
```

In Controller method:

```
    public function afficherPhoto()
    {
        $photo_cl = new Photo();
        $photo = null;
        if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
            $photo = $photo_cl->afficherPhoto((int)$_GET['id']);
        }
        require_once('vues/affiche-photo.php');
    }
```

In the view file `affiche-photo.php` (`fichier` and `titre` must correspond to the DB table field names):

```
        <article>
            <img src="photos/<?= $photo->fichier; ?>" width="500" />
            <h2><?= $photo->titre; ?></h2>
        </article>
```

Comment: I used your code but I still have the same problem

Comment: Ok, debug it with ``print_r($photo)`` / ``var_dump($photo)`` and show what returns your DB request. Put it inside ``else {}`` part. Then validate your URL link ``src="photos/object_property_value_fichier"``, it should return an image.

Comment: It tells me that the variable $photo is not define in
C:\xampp\htdocs\BookPhoto\vues\affiche-photo.php on line 3

Comment: That because method ``afficherPhoto`` returns an object from DB, which is not a class instance of ``class Photo``. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
The problem was indeed with the echo. I finally just change my affiche-photo.php :

```php
<?php
$titre = 'Une photo de mon book';
if (is_null($photo)):
    $contenu = "Cette photo n'existe pas.";
else:
    ob_start();
?>
        <article>
            <img src="photos/<?php echo $photo->getFichier(); ?>" width="500" />
            <h2><?php echo $photo->getTitre(); ?></h2>
        </article>
<?php
    $contenu = ob_get_clean();
endif;
require_once('layout.php');
```

and my liste-photos.php where I changed the path in the href :

```
<?php
$titre = 'Mon book';
ob_start();
?>
  <article>
    <?php foreach ($photos as $photo): ?>
      <a href="?id=<?= $photo->getId() ?>">
      <img src="photos/<?= $photo->getFichier() ?>" width="250"/>
      </a>
      <h2><?= $photo->getTitre() ?></h2> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </article>
  <?php
$contenu = ob_get_clean();
require_once('layout.php');
```